# How to configure a collection related to the resource?

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I use Doctrine ORM and have got 2 entity classes marked as `ApiResource`:

- `Customer` (with `Get` operation enabled)
- `Transaction` (with `GetCollection` operation enabled)

When I call the API endpoint for the `Customer` resource the response contains an array containing the `Customer`’s `Transaction`s.

Is there a way to configure how those related `Transaction`s are returned: order, limited number of items, filter?

I configured the `Transaction` resource using e.g. paginationItemsPerPage but this only affects the API endpoint for the `Transaction` resource itself, right?

Comment: I think you can't filter or order relations without touching the normalization, but it could be hard to do so